# SQL Server string to varbinary conversion

Tags: sql, string, type-conversion, varbinary

Ok, the problem is that there's a merger or join that needs to be done on 2 tables.  One has file content stored as an [image] type or varbinary(max), the other has the file content stored as a hex string. if I upload the same content into both tables

the content as string (bytearray to string) would look like like this...

```
'application/vnd.xfdl;content-encoding="base64-gzip"
H4sIAAAAAAAAC+y9e1fjONI4/H9/Cg173idwFgIJl+5m6MzPJAayE+KsnXQPs8+cHJMY8HZi57ET
aObMh3918UW2Jcdyrmbg7E7HtqpUpSqVSqWSdPHLj/EIPBuOa9rWl51K+WgHGNbAHprW45edpqYc
fPp0+vmgsvNL7cPFb1eNFoDlLffLztN0Ojk/PHx5eSl3Zo4hDx+N8sAeH6Iyh2fl0x1S8Hwwc6f2'    
...
```

the content as image looks like (and this is ultimately what I want it to look like)

```
0x6170706C69636174696F6E
```

if I do select `convert(varbinary(MAX), @contentAsString)` I get `0x6100700070006C00690063006100740069006F006E`

it appears as though the conversion is on target but putting two zeros (00) between each, I'll call it a byte for lack of better words.

I've tried all sorts of more complicated methods posted across forums but to no avail.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your example the other table contains base64 encoded and not hex string.  Is the example what you intend to receive as output or is it the actual source format?

Comment: That is not a hex string. question is misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so the padded 00 has been answered.

```
DECLARE @hexStringNVar nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @hexStringVAR varchar(max)

SET @hexStringNVar = '{my hex string as described above}'
SET @hexStringVAR = '{my hex string as described above}'

select CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), @hexStringNVar)) = 0x6100700070006C00690063...
select CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), @hexStringVAR)) = 0x6170706C6963...
```

The `00` padding is because of Unicode or `NVARCHAR` as opposed to `VARCHAR`.

So, since the stored data is in `nvarchar(max)`, the solution is this:

```
select CAST(cast(@hexStringNVar as varchar(max)) as varbinary(max)) = 0x6170706C6963...
```

I'm sure that `convert` would work just as well but my target SQL Server is 2005.

Comment: or change the storage type to `varchar` instead of it being `nvarchar`

Answer (score 33):

From [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx)

> In SQL Server 2008, these conversions are even more easier since we
>   added support directly in the CONVERT built-in function. The code
>   samples below show how to perform the conversion(s):
>
> ```
> declare @hexstring varchar(max);
>
> set @hexstring = '0xabcedf012439';
>
> select CONVERT(varbinary(max), @hexstring, 1);
>
> set @hexstring = 'abcedf012439';
>
> select CONVERT(varbinary(max), @hexstring, 2);
>
> go
>
> declare @hexbin varbinary(max);
>
> set @hexbin = 0xabcedf012439;
>
> select
>    CONVERT(varchar(max), @hexbin, 1),
>    CONVERT(varchar(max), @hexbin, 2);
>
> go
> ```

Comment: The @hexstring looks like this: 
`'application/vnd.xfdl;content-encoding="base64-gzip"
H4sIAAAAAAAAC+y9e1fjONI4/H9/Cg173idwFgIJl+5m6MzPJAayE+KsnXQPs8+cHJMY8HZi57ET'...`
target binary = `0x6170706C69636174696F6E`
`select CONVERT(varbinary(max), @hexstring);` - succeeded, but wrong binary 0x6100700070006C00690063006100740069006F006E
`select CONVERT(varbinary(max), @hexstring, 1);` - failed "Error converting data type nvarchar to varbinary"
`select CONVERT(varbinary(max), @hexstring, 2);` - failed "Error converting data type nvarchar to varbinary"

Comment: I've tested almost everything I can find online such as "From MSDN" type posts.  The question remaining is, why does the generic CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), @hexstring) pad every 2 characters with 00 and is there a way to get rid of it?